# how to configure laravel site on localhost using xampp

Tags: laravel-5, xampp, localhost

I am trying to configure the site in **localhost** which is developed on laravel.

Now I am trying to configure it on my local Machine, using **xampp version 3.2.1** and **php version 5.6.11** & **mysql DB**.

I am able to configure it but other than home page all links get **404 page not found** error

any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the `rewrite_module` in apache's configuration file.

If you are not aware of how to do this, follow below steps:

1) Open apache's configuration file using your favorite text editor. The configuration file generally locates at:{apache_dir}/conf/httpd.conf
If you are using XAMPP or WAMP package then you will find the file at:`{xampp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf` (or)
`{wamp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf`

2) Search for the following string:`#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` and uncomment it (remove the '#' sign).

3) Now search for another string `AllowOverride None` and replace it by `AllowOverride All`

4) Finally save the changes, close your text editor and restart your apache server.

Hope this will help you, Thank you.

Comment: can you eccept my own answer please...!

Comment: help me to increase my repution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712182/finding-the-total-sum-of-numbers-in-an-array-in-java-recursively/41712224#41712224
like amy answer here

Comment: I can not accept your answer, answers can be accepted only by whom the question was posted. However I already cast my vote to your question :). Have a good day.